# Cannot install voice on MacBook

Tags: macbook, macbook-pro

Because I want to use only some voices, I deleted all the 
voices(/System/Library/Speech/Voices) and tried to reinstall the voices via Accessibility.

However, the voice cannot be used even they are downloaded as the following pictures showed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

There are files downloaded as below but the voice cannot be selected as the above picture showed.

[image]

My MacBook is "MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)" and macOS is "10.14.6".

Could anyone tell me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you have access to someone with a Mac?  Just copy the voice files from their install.

Comment: How did you delete something out of `/System`? Are you running with SIP (System Integrity Protection) disabled? What is the output of `csrutil status`?